# Using xCmd to invoke remote file

Tags: windows, remote-access

To invoke a jar file, which is placed on a different Windows shared folder; I am using [xCmd](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/xcmd-an-alternative-to-psexec/) utility. It invokes it and continues to open that connection and shows me the stderr/stout of that jar file, which I don’t need. I just need xCmd to invoke the jar file then quit, rest of the things will be taken care by jar file.

Is there any other utility or way just to invoke remote file.
The only problem, which I am facing, is that it is not quitting connection just after invoking. Besides it, it starts displaying me stdout.

Answer (score 0):

*xCmd* is actually a clone of **[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)** which itself is usually bundled in PsTools.